# What does model.to(device) return and where is the documentation for it?

Tags: python, pytorch

I found documentation for [models](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/modules.html) but not the specefic api documentation for model.to().

ChatGPT had told me conflicting info. that it returns a copy of the model and also that it returns a reference to the model.

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
modelBigram0 = BigramLanguageModel(vocab_size)
modelBigram1 = modelBigram0.to(device)
```

If I had the documentation for model.to() this would help.

Comment: It's right [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.to). There's a link to it on that page you linked to. It appears to return the module; likely so it can be chained.

Comment: It's quite rare in Python for an API to return a copy of an object.  You'll almost always get a reference to the object itself.

Comment: @bobbywang I've never touched Pytorch, so I'm hesitant to say much. I'm just rehearsed at interpreting docs. If you click the link I posted, it should jump to the method docs. The three `to(...)` blocks show the different arguments you can pass to it. If you scroll down a ways to `Returns:` and `Return type:`, you can see that it returns `self` (the object the method was called on), and the type of that is `Module`. The answer below has been updated as well to reflect that.

Comment: @bobbywang All I did was go to the page you linked to, searched (ctrl+f) on the page for `to(`, and that lead to a link with the text `to()`, which I clicked on to get to the part that I linked to. It may mot look like it on the surface, but the `to()` text is a link. Always check for that.

Comment: According to you all and the docs, the snippet above is redundant.  This is code by one of the best AI guys, Karposky.  So I'm not sure why he did this.  He seems to think they modelBigram0 and modelBigram1 are not the same.

Comment: so this AI genius, does not know you should not create excess variables for no reason? ... can someone verify?  He probably could not read the docs! they are confusing!

Answer (score 0):

**The method modifies the module in-place**. It is used to move the model between devices (cpu/gpu). The return value is a self-reference to the calling object.

The documentation is [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.to) as @Carcigenicate already pointed out in the comment.

Example usage according to documentation:

```py
modelBigram0 = BigramLanguageModel(vocab_size)
modelBigram0.to(device)
```

There is no need to use two separate variables. In your example, both of them contain reference to the same object which is stored in the system memory or gpu memory only once.

Comment: It has a return value, what makes you think that it does not?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I have edited my answer. The method returns reference to itself and does not make any copy. You can confirm this by checking the condition `modelBigram0 is modelBigram1`

Comment: The return value is a self-reference to the calling object.